# uploading asp.net pages

Tags: asp.net, web, upload

sry if this is trivial

which files from my asp.net solution should i upload using filezilla in my website please?

thank you

These errors are appearing in vs:

> Connecting to
>   ftp://my____website.com/... Publishing
>   folder /... Unable to add
>   'Answer.aspx' to the Web site.  Could
>   not find a Web server at
>   'my____website.com' on port 21. Please
>   check to make sure that the Web server
>   name is valid and your proxy settings
>   are set correctly. If you are sure
>   that everything is correct, the Web
>   server may be temporarily out of
>   service. Unable to add 'Default.aspx'
>   to the Web site.  Could not find a Web
>   server at 'my____website.com' on port
>   21. Please check to make sure that the Web server name is valid and your
>   proxy settings are set correctly. If
>   you are sure that everything is
>   correct, the Web server may be
>   temporarily out of service. Unable to
>   add 'Web.config' to the Web site. 
>   Could not find a Web server at
>   'my____website.com' on port 21. Please
>   check to make sure that the Web server
>   name is valid and your proxy settings
>   are set correctly. If you are sure
>   that everything is correct, the Web
>   server may be temporarily out of
>   service. Unable to add
>   'my____website.bmp' to the Web site. 
>   Could not find a Web server at
>   'my____website.com' on port 21. Please
>   check to make sure that the Web server
>   name is valid and your proxy settings
>   are set correctly. If you are sure
>   that everything is correct, the Web
>   server may be temporarily out of
>   service. Publishing folder App_Data...
>   Publishing folder bin... Unable to add
>   'bin/my____website.dll' to the Web
>   site.  Could not find a Web server at
>   'my____website.com' on port 21. Please
>   check to make sure that the Web server
>   name is valid and your proxy settings
>   are set correctly. If you are sure
>   that everything is correct, the Web
>   server may be temporarily out of
>   service. Unable to add
>   'bin/my____website.pdb' to the Web
>   site.  Could not find a Web server at
>   'my____website.com' on port 21. Please
>   check to make sure that the Web server
>   name is valid and your proxy settings
>   are set correctly. If you are sure
>   that everything is correct, the Web
>   server may be temporarily out of
>   service.
>
> ## ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped
>
> ========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I think you should upload all files to run your site properly :)

Comment: .cs files should definitively not be deployed to the live server...

Comment: Your errors look like you're not actually connected to your site's directory via FTP correctly.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong. I go to Build menu. Click on publish. Type in the ftp (ftp://my____website.com) and enter my login name and password and wait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio, you can use the Publish functionality:

1. In the Solution Explorer, right-click on the root (your project/website name)
2. There should be an option called Publish.
3. Select how/where you wish to publish
4. In the popup, ensure that the "Only files needed to run this application" option is selected

This will publish only the files needed to your website.

Comment: Also, once you're comfortable with publishing, you should consider encrypting your config files.

Comment: I published using the ftp i was given...but nothing came :S

Comment: Did you get this working? It looks like your Server is wrong ('my____website.com' looks fishy). It should probably be the IP address of your host, or your domain name, depending on your hosting arrangement.

Maybe your server requires secure FTP (SFTP), have your tried that (port 22)?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your web project and choose Publish. Change the output to an empty directory and copy all files that get put there.

Also see this MSDN article for more details on Publishing your site

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(VS.80).aspx